# SDG with batch size >1?

Tags: pytorch, batchsize, sgd

I'm taking the "Deep NNs with PyTorch" course by IBM and I encountered lab examples where SDG is used for optimizer while batch size is >1 in DataLoader.

If I understand correctly, SGD would perform gradient descent with only 1 training example in each step, so it this case how would the SGD interact with each batch of training example?

For example, if batch size = 20, would the SGD optimizer perform 20 GD steps in each batch? If this is the case, then does that mean no matter what batch size I set for DataLoader, the SGD optimizer would just perform (# of training example) GD steps in one epoch?

```
Layers = [2, 50, 3]
model = Net(Layers)
learning_rate = 0.10
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=data_set, batch_size=20)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
LOSS = train(data_set, model, criterion, train_loader, optimizer, epochs=100)

def train(data_set, model, criterion, train_loader, optimizer, epochs=100):
LOSS = []
ACC = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for x, y in train_loader:
        print(x, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        yhat = model(x)
        loss = criterion(yhat, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        LOSS.append(loss.item())
    ACC.append(accuracy(model, data_set))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> if batch size = 20, would the SGD optimizer perform 20 GD steps in
> each batch?

No. Batch size = 20 means, it would process all the 20 samples and then get the scalar loss. Based on that it would backpropagate the error. And that is one step of GD.

This is known as **minibatch SGD**, instead of taking 1 input like in SGD, it considers 20 and then everything else stays the same.

Comment: So is this the same as batch GD? Are they the same thing because I thought SGD strictly means performing GD with just the lost of 1 sample?

Comment: If batch size = 1 the minibatch SGD is same as SGD